# Configure modsecurity to limit number of parameter?

Tags: apache, mod-security

I have just read about new technique DoS that called HashDoS. 
Details about it, https://cryptanalysis.eu/blog/2011/12/28/effective-dos-attacks-against-web-application-plattforms-hashdos/

This DoS technique POST a large number of parameter and trigger worse case of hashtable algorithm. Web server will take more time to do the job.

They said:

> So you can keep about 10.000 Core i7 CPU cores busy processing PHP
>   requests using a gigabit internet connection. Alternatively for
>   ASP.NET, 30,000 Core2 CPU cores, or for Java Tomcat 100,000 Core i7
>   CPU cores, or for CRuby 1.8 1,000,000 Core i7 CPU cores, can be kept
>   busy with a single gigabit connection.

So, I want to limit number of parameter in POST content for my company website.
I know modsecurity can do that, but I'm not familiar with modsecurity.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modsecurity can limit the total length of, but not the number of, parameters. There is a module that has recently been updated with this feature (it's in beta): ModIfier: http://yoyo.org/~steve/mod_ifier.html

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to understand modsecurity. 
Then I found OWASP Modsecurity Core Rule Set, in file modsecurity_crs_23_request_limits.conf there was a rule that limited number of arguments in a request.

On my company webserver, using modsecurity core rule too, but there's not have this file. I don't know why :(

You can see it here (from line 30):
http://mod-security.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/mod-security/crs/tags/2.2.3/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_23_request_limits.conf?revision=1882&view=markup

Answer (score 0):

You can find a great article that describes mod_security options on defending this here : http://blog.spiderlabs.com/2012/01/modsecurity-mitigations-for-aspnet-hashtable-dos-vulnerability-cve-2011-3414.html